# Should I call 20 external APIs in parrallel?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, parallel-processing, spring-webflux

I'm helping to design a spring boot project/service which calls 20 external APIs, aggregates that data and returns a single json

We are using a reactive model using Flux/Mono. Should we be calling these in parrallel or would that introduce problems with handling resources. Or should we just call them asynchronously

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Point of information.  I am pretty sure that parallel and asynchronous mean the same thing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is making the following assumptions:

- The returned single json string can be cacheable.
- There are default/error values that could be returned for external apis that error out.
- Returned external apis have different service level agreements (meaning you just can't make 100's of requests over and over again).

## TL;DR

Make the requests in an asynchronous way.

## Longer Answer

I would consider making each separate external api as its own object/class.  Hopefully you could use a single interface for these objects, but in general each will be its own object.  This is because you will most likely have different service level agreements with each external api.  This would include how many requests you can may a second/minute/hour/etc...  There will be different api-keys or usernames/passwords.  There will be similar or different error handling behavior, caching strategies, default/error return values for all of these external apis.

Then there should be an aggregation class/object that sits in front of all the external api objects that will create the object that represents the single json string.